# How can I list the plugins (BHOs) that Internet Explorer uses, from my program?

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, bho

I need to retrieve, in my Win32 standalone program, **a list of currently installed Internet Explorer add-ons** (Browser Helper Objects), and - if possible - their enabled/disabled status.

Since anti-spyware programs (or e.g. [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/cs-cz/sysinternals/bb963902)) can get this list from somewhere, is there a simple way to request this list **programatically**?

**EDIT**:
Thanks to @[Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48003/stefan), who pointed me to the right registry keys (**all HKLM**):

```
// BHOs
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\Browser Helper Objects 
// IE toolbars
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar
// IE extensions
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Extensions
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The BHOs are registered under

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\Browser Helper Objects
```

IE toolbars are registered under

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar
```

Answer (score 0):

I use HijackThis.

[http://www.trendsecure.com/portal/en-US/tools/security_tools/hijackthis/overview]

It shows a list of BHOs (along with a -lot- of other useful information), but unfortunately, it doesn't show enabled/disabled status.

Comment: Thanks; I'm aware that it's possible to find this list manually, but I need to do this from a program/script.